# Porque brasileiros chamam Advogados(as) de Doutor(a)?

Tags: português-brasileiro

Segundo o [Wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doutoramento):

> Doutorado é um grau acadêmico concedido por uma instituição de ensino superior
> universitário, que pode ser uma universidade, um centro universitário,
> uma faculdade isolada, com o propósito de certificar academicamente a
> capacidade do candidato para desenvolver investigação num determinado
> campo da ciência

Então por que um graduado em direito também recebe esse tratamento?

Comment: Mesmo sem ter concluído um doutorado com aprovação, existem profissionais no Brasil e em muitos outros países que recebem o título de "doutor".  Os que me vem a mente no momento, são: médicos, dentistas, e advogados,  Nos Estados Unidos da América, médicos e cientistas recebem esse título.  Talvez advogados, mas não tenho certeza.  Interessante é que no Reino Unido, só os médicos clínicos recebem o título Dr.  Os médicos cirurgiões não.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Existe uma lei do tempo do Império que concede o título de Doutor para os advogados. Essa lei promulgada por Dom Pedro I em 11 de agosto de 1827 estabeleceu a Lei do Império que criou dois cursos de Ciências Jurídicas e Sociais.

> Art. 9.º - Os que freqüentarem os cinco annos de qualquer dos Cursos,
>   com approvação, conseguirão o gráo de Bachareis formados. Haverá
>   tambem o gráo de Doutor, que será conferido áquelles que se
>   habilitarem com os requisitos que se especificarem nos Estatutos, que
>   devem formar-se, e sò os que o obtiverem, poderão ser escolhidos para
>   Lentes.

Fontes: [EPD-Online](http://blog.epdonline.com.br/curiosidades/advogado-e-chamado-de-doutor-no-direito/) e [JusBrasil](https://pauloabreu14.jusbrasil.com.br/artigos/431235782/advogado-e-doutor)

Answer (score 3):

Ainda que as outras respostas tenham sido bastante boas, é importante acrescentar que isto não é exclusivo do Brasil.

Em Portugal também existe (embora seja cada vez menos frequente) uma certa tendência de chamar Mestre/Doutor a pessoas com cursos superiores que não sejam necessariamente mestrados/doutoramentos (da mesma forma que se usa o arcaico "fidalgo" para se referir a alguém mais rico/abastado, ainda que o regime feudal já não exista há muito tempo).

Isto acontece particularmente em zonas mais pobres e envelhecidas, em que ter um curso superior é algo muito raro. Mostra um pouco a "hierarquia social" é uma noção muito real na mentalidade das pessoas, o que faz sentido tendo em conta o contexto histórico em que elas viveram (ditadura).

Comment: Sim, exatamente. Tambem na América Latina em geral. Eu recentemente fiz uma interpretação (ing.<>esp.) para um depoimento, e o velhinho (87 anos) que estava explicando a sua situácão aos advogados, pensava que estava falando comigo, e antes de cada resposta dizia: Doctorcita [sei-lá-que]. Eu simplesmente não traduzi mas achei tão bonitinho. Essa minha experiência quadra com a sua resposta perfeitamente. O velhinho era   campônes colombiano....

Answer (score 0):

Os títulos académicos eram no geral 3: doutor, engenheiro, arquitecto.

- O primeiro dos títulos era o mais abrangente, especificava-se "doutor em direito", "doutor em medicina", "doutor em letras", etc...
- O título de engenheiro era mais estrito, no princípio do séc.XX só havia uma dúzia de cursos de engenharia.
- O título de arquitecto era o mais específico, sendo só atribuido aos licenciados em arquitectura.

O uso dos títulos é uma herança história do sistema de ensino superior. Reflecte a divisão do saber como era vista à época. Mas também a pouca especialização na maioria das profissões, que então não requeriam estudos superiores.

O direito e a advocacia existem desde a antiguidade, de maneira que chamar "doutor" a uma advogado é a forma abreviada de chamar-lhe: "doutor em direito".

Comment: Não sei se isso explica, afinal você ainda pode fazer um doutorado voltado pro direito, e ai sim ter o titulo de doutor, não apenas um bacharelado

Comment: Aí diz-se: "doutorado em" na vez de: "doutor em".